# M-x shell doesn't know about installed apps

Tags: shell, path

I have to launch almost any application by specifying the whole path which is annoying.

For example, `git` works fine, but `lua` does not. Both are installed in the same place:

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
$ which lua
/usr/local/bin/lua
```

How to make `M-x` `shell` behave like my standard shell? Or maybe there's a decent shell emulator as a package?

`echo $SHELL` outputs `/bin/bash`.

Comment: What are your shell and path variables? (Do `echo $SHELL` and `echo $PATH` in an emacs shell).

Comment: What about `term` or `eshell` ?

Comment: @dshepherd please see an update :)

Comment: @Scony all of them do the same :/

Comment: Well, as @dshepherd mentioned, you are missing `/usr/local/bin` in `PATH`. `git` is working probably only because there is symlink in `/bin`. Try `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` in emacs terminal. You can also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606954/path-and-exec-path-set-but-emacs-does-not-find-executable

Comment: Where does he say what his `$PATH` is? I can't see it! :( If an incorrect `PATH` is the problem then we might need to know more about how you are launching emacs (emacs will inherit `PATH` from wherever it is invoked).

Comment: @Scony your advice helped and fixed the issue. Please write an answer so I could accept it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, as @dshepherd mentioned, you are missing `/usr/local/bin` in PATH. `git` is working probably only because there is symlink in `/bin`. Try `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` in emacs terminal.

You can also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606954/path-and-exec-path-set-but-emacs-does-not-find-executable

In the future, in case of similar issue, checking PATH (`echo $PATH`) should be first thing you should do.